# Struts2 httpServletResponse.reset explication

Tags: java, servlets, struts2, httpresponse

I m working on an old project and i see this method that do a `httpservletresponse.reset` and i m surprise to see this...

```
private boolean checkAjaxRequest(ActionInvocation pInvocation) {
    boolean ajax = false;
    ActionContext ctxAction = pInvocation.getInvocationContext();
    if (ctxAction.getParameters() == null) {
        LOG.warn("Impossible de déterminer s'il s'agit d'une requête HTTP");
    } else {
        String[] p = (String[]) ctxAction.getParameters().get("mpoajax");
        ajax = (p != null && p.length > 0 && "true".equals(p[0]));

        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) ctxAction.get(HTTP_RESPONSE);
        res.reset();
    }
    return ajax;
}
```

I can't explain why i have this because its a project that we have get from another society long time ago, and i don't have svn log before we get this code. so svn log don't show anything.

this code is in Struts2 interceptor so it was called for each http request and i have a login problem because of this line and when i put this line in comment all work fine.

So my question is can i remove this line whithout any risk for the rest of the application or i need to test some particulary call?

Does exist a good reason to do a reset?

i check the API, and i understand that the response is clear but i don't know why in my case its done. So i m looking for suposition if you have :)

thanks a lot.